# Displaying object as image inside a list component

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

### Problem

I have to display an object as an image inside a list component based on a particular count (`intNote`). While using an image path from specific location the images are displayed.

### Question

How can I display an object as an image inside a list component?

### Source

The JRXML:

```
<subDataset name="Q2">
        <field name="strVert" class="java.awt.Image"/>      
</subDataset>

<field name="intNote" class="java.lang.Integer"/> 

<componentElement>
    <reportElement x="130" y="72" width="25" height="35"/>
    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal" ignoreWidth="true">
        <datasetRun subDataset="Q2">
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource($F{intNote})]]></dataSourceExpression>
        </datasetRun>
        <jr:listContents height="35" width="25">
            <image isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement x="3" y="10" width="16" height="17" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                </graphicElement>
                <imageExpression class="java.awt.Image"><![CDATA[$F{strVert}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </jr:listContents>
    </jr:list>
</componentElement>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jasper you can display images by putting the current image location instead of the varible intNote.it is the only possible way to get the image in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make $F{strVert} class as java.io.InputStream